# Namespace or module "NagLibrary" not found, but reference successfully added (?)

Tags: f#

I have a 3rd party .dll that I have successfully added as a reference in both a VS 2010 C# project and an F# VS 2010 project.  I can view the contents in the object browser in both cases, but the F# version won't let me "open" the library.  It works fine in the C# project (with the "using" directive), and I can write a program that uses the contents of this particular .dll.  I have not had any trouble with other .dlls in F#/VS 2010/.NET 4.0 on Windows 7.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?  Or how I could debug this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what the csc.exe and fsc.exe command-lines have for the library in question (in VS, open the 'Output Window' after a rebuild), to see if they both have the same reference (e.g. `-r:Path\Library.dll`).

And to be clear, you're saying

```
open NagLibrary
```

in F# yields the error message in the title, but

```
using NagLibrary;
```

in C# works and opens the namespace?

Comment: yes, what you have said above is what I am experiencing.

When I build the F# project (without attempting to "open NagLibrary"), I do in fact see the following:

-r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\NAG\NAG Library for .NET 64Bit\NagLibrary64.dll"  So it seems to be finding it properly (?)

Comment: Hmm it looks like 64bit/32bit mismatch maybe? Try changing the platform of your project in configuration manager

Comment: Does csc.exe find the same library/path?

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  When I compile the C# project it doesn't show any output about the libraries being linked in.  It just says that the build succeeded and then I can run it.  But it is definitely the same .dll.  And I've tried x86, x64, Any CPU configurations and none of them work for the F# version.

Comment: Tools\Options\Projects and Solutions\Build and Run\MSBuild project output verbosity - set it to 'Diagnostic'.  Then 'Clean' both projects.  'Build' C#, and inspect the very long output in Output Window for NagLibrary.  Same for F#.  If MSBuild resolution differs, describe that difference.  If the same, then perhaps mail fsbugs at microsoft dot com for more help.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  This is very helpful.  The output is going to take me a while to go through.  I think this may be a problem with the vendor's .dll at this point.  I am voting this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you reference the path within the script using the double "\" convention
for me this worked

```
#r "C:\homeware\\blp\\api\\APIv3\\DotnetAPI\\v3.4.5.4\\lib\\Bloomberglp.Blpapi.dll"

open Bloomberglp.Blpapi
```

Comment: Note that if you use verbatim strings like @"C:\homeware\...", you don't have to write double backslashes.